# Mount a drive at login time

Tags: networking, debian

I need to mount a drive at login time. I have the home directories in the server, and when a user logs in at a client machine (debian 7), I need to mount his directory temporally at a mount point, until the user logs out..
I followed this instructions: http://debianhelp.co.uk/nfs.htm and tried to modify the `/etc/fstab` file, but it works for mount at boot time.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: At login you can mess with `/etc/profile.d/` or `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`. At logout, not so much. Or you can try to set as shell for those users a wrapper which does mount, run a shell, umount.

Answer (score 2):

One potentially good choice to mount things when a user logins is to use the [pam_mount](http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/) plugin.  This module adds a feature to mount volumes at login, and with the correct settings I believe you can even pass the user's authentication credentials to the mount command.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mounting from fstab, which has a tendency to time out and then be stuck in a broken state(obviously not good for a home directory)

I recommend using auto FS which will mount the share on use and keep it active while it is needed. Then if it times out it will remount whenever the user needs it, for as long as they need it.

a good starting point can be referenced here (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_auto.master.htm or https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-nfs-config-autofs.html)

But basically what you need to do is reference the auto.master file
in:

> /etc/auto.master

This should reference some example locations, such as

> /misc /etc/auto.misc

you could then make an /etc/auto.home file based on the auto.misc

You will need to add the:

> /home /etc/auto.home

Line to your auto.master, and edit your copied auto.home script to meet your timeout needs.

Doing so generally does require centralized authentication to function 100% properly.

Comment: I will look the references. Does autofs work when log in in the system? Or after login?

Comment: it works on access. So as soon as a user needs access to the directory. It is intended as a network smart seamless mounting system

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use automount/autofs. However, volumes will be mounted not at login time but when the user tries to access them. There is no practical difference. Also, they will be unmounted after the user being inactive for some time.

Please, have a look at this [Ubuntu autofs page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs).

Best regards